# Java runtime method selection using "super" in the subclass and "this" in the super class

Tags: java, jvm, this, super, overloading

I found this apparently odd behaviour in method-overriding/overloading of Java, that has been boggling my mind. The call in the `Main()` method prints out "**B_A**", while I would expect it to be "**B_B**".

```
package one;
public class A {
    public void method(A a){ System.out.println("A_A");  }
    public void method(B b) { System.out.println("A_B");  }
    public void method(){ this.method(this);  }
}

package one;
public class B extends A {
    public void method(A a) { System.out.println("B_A"); }
    public void method(B b) { System.out.println("B_B"); }
    public void method(){ super.method(); }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B bb = new B();

        bb.method();      //prints B_A, expected B_B        
    } 
}
```

I break down the process as the following:

1. The compiler selects method `method()` of class B
2. During runtime, JVM calls method `method()` of its superclass via `super()`
3. <s>`this.method(this)` gets called from within class A, but `this` refers to an instance of class B, therefore translating to method `method(B b)` of class B.</s> <- *this statement is wrong (thanks Alexey Romanov and pvg). Selection of methods, overloading-wise, is always done at compile time. That is, that method translates to .m(A) before runtime. At runtime, the proper overriding method is chosen.*
4. Why is the method `method(A a)` of class B being invoked, instead?

My guess is that the JVM, when it selects a subclass method during runtime, starts looking up into a table of overloaded methods, where is a fixed precedence and the methods with a arguments of higher classes in the hierarchy are looked up first. That is, it doesn't go straight for `B.method(B b)`, instead it looks it up into such a table and it's ok with the first compatible method - `B.method(A a)` - as B is A.

Another idea is that the call `this.method(this)` in class A calls `B.method(A a)` straight out, but that would imply that the same symbol (`this`) *in the same context* could refer to different objects.

Any help sorting this out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Method overloading is resolved at compile time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this.method(this) gets called from within class A, but this refers to an instance of class B, therefore translating to method method(B b) of class B.

This step is wrong. Note that *overloaded* methods (that is, multiple methods with same name) are resolved by the compiler. In class `A`, `this` has type `A`, so `this.method(this)` calls `method(A a)`. Then at runtime `B`'s implementation of *that* method is used.

> Another idea is that the call this.method(this) in class A calls B.method(A a) straight out,

No, it calls just `method(A a)`. It doesn't know anything about `B`.

> but that would imply that the same symbol (this) in the same context could refer to different objects.

It wouldn't and doesn't imply that.

I'll also note that `public void method(){ super.method(); }` in `B` doesn't affect anything in this question.

Comment: Thank you, Alexey. So, the compiler translates every "this" to their own classes when they are arguments, not just in the signatures of methods but also for each method call? (While targets are choses at runtime?)

Comment: > I'll also note that public void method(){ super.method(); } in B doesn't affect anything in this question.

Well, the target is now of B class. If it was called by an instance of class A, the output would differ.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati every argument has a compile-time type. Method overloading is then resolved on the basis of that type. It doesn't matter if it's `this` or anything else. This is done exclusively at compile time. What is done at runtime is resolution based on the actual runtime type of the _receiver_ of the call.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati I mean that if you remove `method()` override in `B`, the output doesn't change. Not only for the specific case of `B bb = new B(); bb.method();`, but for any other ways to call it.

Comment: @pvg I can't understand how the compiler can choose the method "this.method(this);" before running it.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati at compile-time, method A is chosen because the compile-time type of  the `this` argument is A. At runtime, the implementation of method A from class B is executed because the runtime-type of the receiver `this` is B. You can think of it as picking the 'signature' of the method at compile time while the particular implementation that is executed is what is dynamically selected at runtime.

Comment: @pvg So, since 'this' is B at runtime and B is A, it fits with what the compiler decided. Is it like so?

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. What the compiler and runtime do are somewhat orthogonal in this case. The compiler decides which of the method signatures within the class match the invocation. Forget B exists and consider what the compiler must do in `A.method` - it has to generate code that invokes method A. The runtime gets to decide which _implementation_ of method A runs, because subclasses can provide their own implementations. The decision it's going to be A happens at compile time. At runtime, it's a matter of picking the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above discussed answers,

```
B bb = new B();
bb.method(); // ... 1 ... prints B_A

A ab = new B();
ab.method(); // ... 2 ... prints B_A

A aa = new A();
aa.method(); // ... 3 ... prints A_A
```

Irrespective of the reference type in the first and second case, the objects are for `class B`.
The `method()` call for `bb` and `ab` invokes the `super.method()` block.
This calls the `method()` from `A class` and passes reference of its own class to `this.method(this)` i.e. `this.method(A);`
This invokes the method `method(A a)` under B at run-time (method overridding).

In the third case, `this.method(this)` invokes the method `method(A a)` under class A.
This happens at the compile time itself (method overloading)

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation.